Python interpreter does not execute valid code. The interpreter closes out and does not execute the code. VSCode hangs when code asks for user input
Recently I have run into the issue of Python programs not executing and code from VSCode will not execute valid code. The terminal with crash, the pipe symbol ' | ' that should be blinking in the terminal to accept user input is frozen. Running the .py files themselves as scripts cause the interpreter to display, but it will close out and not execute the code. I have tried setting the PATH variable to the location of Python.exe and resintalling Python. Neither of these things solved this issue.
I have tested this problem on a simple HelloWorld.py and it has the same behavior.
I have tried setting the PATH variable to the correct filepath. I have deleted the filepaths from the PATH variable, I have uninstalled python 3.12.3 and reinstalled it, and reboot my PC. The VSCode terminal still hangs when the code asks for user input, and does not execute code even when the code is correct (it would return errors if not correct). Running executables closes out the interpreter without the code being executed. This has never happened before, I haven't coded in Python in awhile and I have since installed other languages I've used in my college classes so I haven't been regularly coding. However, some scripts I created months ago that would run without error, now do not execute.
I am on Windows 10. What other troubleshooting steps are worth trying? My last resort is to reformat my PC to fix whatever got messed up in the system files.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Can you follow the instructions of qiuck start to reinstall python and vscode python extension?
